# Relative maximum and minimum of the modulus of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=(z -1)(z -4)^{2}$$ Find the lines (through $z=2$) on which $|f(z)|$ has a relative maximum, and the ones on which $|f(z)|$ has a relative minimum.

MY ATTEMPT:

"The line z= 2" is the line where z= 2+ ix for any real number x. Then $f(z)=(z−1)(z−4)^{2} =(2−ix−1)(2−ix−4)^{2}=(1−ix)(−2−ix)^{2}$ . Write out $|f(z)|$ as a function of x, find the derivative, set it equal to 0.

Comment: I'm confused by the usage of the phrase "through $z=2$" here.  What does that mean?

Comment: "The line z= 2" is the line where z= 2+ ix for any real number x. Then $f(z)=(z−1)(z−4)^{2} =(2−ix−1)(2−ix−4)^{2}=(1−ix)(−2−ix)^{2}$ . Write out $|f(z)|$ as a function of x, find the derivative, set it equal to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint to get you started.  Please ask if you require clarification.  If you edit your question to include what you have tried so far I would be more willing to give extra help.

You can parameteize any line going through $z=2$ by

$$
z(t) = 2 + te^{i\theta},
$$

where $\theta$ is the (fixed) angle the line makes with the positive real axis and $t$ is allowed to vary over $\mathbb{R}$.  Substitute this into $|f(z)|$ and differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: "The line z= 2" is the line where z= 2+ ix for any real number x. Then $f(z)=(z−1)(z−4)^{2} =(2−ix−1)(2−ix−4)^{2}=(1−ix)(−2−ix)^{2}$ . Write out $|f(z)|$ as a function of x, find the derivative, set it equal to 0.

Comment: What then I have to do?

Comment: @Breton, that doesn't make sense.  Instead of "The line $z=2$" perhaps you mean $x=2$?  And, the question asks about all lines passing through $z=2$, not just the one for $\theta = \pi/2$.  Does my answer help?  What is unclear?